# Spring LDAP in dev environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm building a spring boot application which use LDAP interaction for authentication but not only. I also retrieve information from LDAP for my users details.

I don't know how to manage this for a dev environment which does not have access to real LDAP.

Ldif file ? Embedded Apache DS Server ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: How do I "mock" a LDAP for my dev environment

Comment: Apologies, may be [this one](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/mocking-out-ldapjndi-in-unit-tests/) can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This works for unit tests but what i'm looking for is for dev runtime. After complementary research, i think that i'll go for an embedded apacheds when running my dev profile

Comment: Glad to know it worked for you. I'll post it as answer. You may wish to accept/upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to mock LDAP in your local environment.

You'll need to,

1. inject JNDI implementation
2. implement JNDI layer
3. write mock which will return desired data.

Refer below mentioned link describing step by step guide to mock LDAP. Tried similar in 2014, hope it work for others.

**Reference:**
https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/mocking-out-ldapjndi-in-unit-tests/

**Note:** Please rephrase your query so that others with similar issue can also benefit it. Happy coding :)